# Grooviest way to join collection of Strings in Groovy 2.x

Tags: string, join, groovy

I just tried:

```
List<String> values = getSomehow()
values.join(",")
```

But see that `join` has been deprecated as of 2.1. So I ask: **How should I be writing this in accordance with the latest preferred/non-deprecated syntax?**

Also, is there a way to accomplish this with closures? I feel like I could be utilizing `collect()` or something similar here.

Comment: `values.iterator().join(",")`

Comment: @alfasin `List` extends `Collection` which extends `Iterable`. There is no need to use `.iterator()`. `values.join(',')` should be good.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You can use the `Iterator` variation of the `join` method in `DefaultGroovyMethods`. It's signature is the same, only the separator needs to be passed in.

It would look like this:

```
List<String> values = ["string1", "string2", "string3"]
String joinedValues = values.join(",")
```

Or you can do it all on one line:

```
String joinedValues = ["string1", "string2", "string3"].join(",")
```

Comment: `List` extends `Collection` which extends `Iterable`. There is no need to use `.iterator()`.

Answer (score 6):

If you're worried about the deprecation issue, the current version of the Groovy JDK (http://groovy-lang.org/gdk.html) shows a `join(String)` method in `Iterable`, `Object[]`, and `Iterator`, none of which are deprecated.

Since all the collections implement `Iterable`, your original syntax was fine.

If you really want to use a closure, then

```
List strings = ['this', 'is', 'a', 'list']
String result = strings.inject { acc, val ->
    "$acc,$val"
}
assert result == 'this,is,a,list'
```

works, but it's certainly not any simpler than just `strings.join(',')`.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use the `Iterable` or `Iterator<Object>` version of `join`:

[`join(Iterator<Object> self, String separator)`](http://beta.groovy-lang.org/docs/latest/html/gapi/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/DefaultGroovyMethods.html#join(Iterator%3CObject%3E,%20java.lang.String))

instead of

[`join(Collection self, String separator)`](http://beta.groovy-lang.org/docs/latest/html/gapi/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/DefaultGroovyMethods.html#join(java.util.Collection,%20java.lang.String)).

This is the only variety of `join` which is deprecated.

`join(Iterable self, String separator)` and `join(Object[] self, String separator)` are few more which are in use.

Answer (score 3):

As I see it in documentation, `join` is deprecated In Collections, but not in Iterable.

```
def joinedValues = (values as Iterable).join ', '
```

Using closures you could try to write it with `.inject`, `head` and `tail`:

```
values.head() + (values.size() > 1 ? values.tail().inject( '' ) { acc, i -> acc+', ' + i } : '')
```